# cross-referencing two long lists; general recommendations?

Tags: lists

I have two collections of things: (1) equations with other information (like citations, conditions for validity, etc) associated with each, and (2) comments about each equation that I want to list separately. So I want to have thousands of items of the form

1. F=ma   (m>0)      [4]
2. v=iR   (R>0)      [32]
   ...

in one list, then a second dynamically cross-referenced list of the form

1. Newton's second law.
2. Ohm's law; see also item 34.
   ...

It would be great to hear opinions on how you'd accomplish this. Right now I'm using the AMS \newtheorem environment for the first list. This generates a counter and I can place a unique label inside each "theorem" so that \ref{} can be used within the second list. But the code is possibly longer than needed for the purpose (with each item in the first list surrounded by \begin{} ... \end{} commands), and it doesn't give me the flexibility to quickly reformat the first list ... maybe to something like

1. [4]   F=ma for m>0
2. [32]  v=iR for R>0
   ...

Should I be using \newenvironment instead of \newtheorem? Or maybe \newcommand, with arguments, somehow (can I tag each command call with a label as I can with an environment call)? Or maybe just some version of the "enumerate" structure that I'm unaware of? Opinions and general ideas would be MUCH appreciated here, as again my lists are thousands of item long and I'd like to settle on an approach before attempting to convert my current code to something better.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems hard to get the real point of your question. You could clarify by adding a minimal compilable code example (MWE). One simple version of the label creation would be to use enumerate and put a label directly after the item command...

Comment: Possibly it's as simple as that ... I never tried to label items in an enumerate environment before ... didn't know I could do that ... let me try!

Comment: Another possibility is to create your own counter and use \refstepcounter to increment it.

Comment: If there's no problem with having lists span dozens of pages, and if I can manage to remove the item indentations, I should be all set!

Comment: How did it work out (you could f.i. self-answer the question)?